# Implementing a small webserver in UWP, html is not sent if I don't dispose of the socket

Tags: c#, sockets, webserver, win-universal-app

I'm implementing a small webserver in UWP, in C#. 
I'm having problems with sending the HTML page back to the client, it only works if I dispose of the socket,if I don't the HTML will not be sent until I stop the server. Fiddler also confirms it, if I don't dispose of the socket, html wont be send.

According to HTTP specifications, the TCP connection shouldn't be closed because everytime a client ask for a page would add overhead.

Here is the relevant piece of code I'm using

```
   private async void Listener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
            {

     string response= await fileNotFound(rootDirectory);
     Byte[] bSendData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
      writer.WriteBytes(bSendData);

        await writer.StoreAsync();
        await writer.FlushAsync();
        args.Socket.Dispose();
    }



    private async Task<string>  fileNotFound(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder rootDirectory)
    {
      Windows.Storage.StorageFile htmlErrorFile= await rootDirectory.GetFileAsync("404.html");
      var properties = await htmlErrorFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        string htmlErrorPage = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n" +
       "Content-Lenght:" + properties.Size + "\r\n" +
         "Content-type: text/html\r\n" +
        "Connection: Keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
htmlErrorPage+= await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(htmlErrorFile);
        return htmlErrorPage;
}
```

Comment: Did you set a `Content-Length` header? If you did not, the only way the client knows the response is over is by shutting down the connection (equivalent to disposing the socket). If still in doubt, attach some Network Monitor traces.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with an error page with the code I added and still, the browser keeps trying to load the page, and according to Fiddler nothing is sent, unless I stop the server running, thats when the webpage will be sent and it'll be shown in the browser

Comment: It seems you are not reading the client request. And, are you sure the file is encoded UTF-8? Otherwise, the file of the size may be larger than the content of it converted into UTF-8.